# why my join does not work with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

```
select memid,max (joindate)as joindate from cd.members a
group by memid

join (select memid from cd.members where firstname = 'Darren' and surname = 'Smith')b 

where a.memid = b.memid
```

Comment: Could you format your query a bit? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Your subquery does not seem to return distinct results. What happens if there are two Darren Smiths in your database?

Comment: Your query is not even remotely close to being correct, syntax wise. Try spending some more time learning SQL. GROUP BY should be at the end, after WHERE and you need join conditions in the ON clause and not WHERE if you're using standard syntax.

Comment: "does not work" is not a good problem description. Did you get an error (then we would like the exact error text), did you get unexpected results (what did you actually get, what did you expect, using what data)?

Comment: Why do you join a table with itself, using the same records? When a.memid = b.memid, first name and surname should be the same as well. What's the point of this subquery and join?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
select a.memid,joindate from (select memid,max (joindate)as joindate from 
cd.members group by memid)a
join (select memid from cd.members where firstname = 'Darren' and surname = 'Smith')b
on (a.memid = b.memid)
```

Be careful, as not grouping by in **b** can led to multiple results for each memid. I also assume that cd.members is coming from a previous query part, as using "." in a table name could be faulty.